# Can't link. Undefined symbols actually present and defined

Tags: linker, undefined, symbols

I have cross platform solution wich is succesfully built for Windows, Linux but during the build at Mac OS X. I have such issue:

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject>, void>::DataType()", referenced from:
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject> >()in ThemeKit.cpp.o
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject> >()in libguiserver.a(MemUtils.cpp.o)
      "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::aum::Color>, void>::DataType()", referenced from:
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::aum::Color> >()in ThemeKit.cpp.o
      "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::ffm::Field>, void>::DataType()", referenced from:
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::ffm::Field> >()in libguiserver.a(FormConverter.cpp.o)
      "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::lfm::EventType>, void>::DataType()", referenced from:
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::lfm::EventType> >()in libguiserver.a(FormConverter.cpp.o)
      "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::lfm::ParsedExpression>, void>::DataType()", referenced from:
          qx::syb::AbsDynInfo const& qx::syb::dynInfo<boost::shared_ptr<qx::lfm::ParsedExpression> >()in libguiserver.a(FormConverter.cpp.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've checked the linker line and it contains object files which contains definition of such symbols.

For example:

```
bash-3.2$ nm -arch x86_64 -U instance*.o | c++filt | grep -i "qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject>, void>::DataType()"
00000000001e6e68 S qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject>, void>::DataType()
0000000000092e48 S qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject>, void>::DataType()
000000000009b170 S qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::DistributedObject>, void>::DataType()
```

It defined several times but another one `"qx::syb::DataType<boost::shared_ptr<qx::aum::Color>, void>::DataType()"` is defined only once and also missed. So this shouldn't be an issue.

I have latest possible environment

```
Mac OS X version:Darwin mac.qx 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
IDE: XCode:4.2
Compiler:gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was connected with compiler optimization. Usage limited optimization like -O1 is possible but more advanced -O2 or -O3 generates such error.